# Simplifying Integrals

Tags: simplifying-expressions

How can I get the expected results of 2 from this integral?

```
Assuming[{U, k} \[Element] Reals && k > 0, (
  Integrate[
    2 (U Exp[\[ImaginaryJ] k x])^2, {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}] //
    HoldForm)/(
  Integrate[(U Exp[\[ImaginaryJ] k x])^2, {x, -\[Infinity], \
\[Infinity]}] // HoldForm) // FullSimplify]
```

Comment: The integral $\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } e^{2 i k x} \, dx$ diverges and Matematica reports it. In view of it I find the question meaningless.

Comment: As the integral diverges, you have Infinity/Infinity what is not defined. The best you can do is to take the definite integral from -a to a and take the limit a->Infinity.

Comment: @DanielHuber: Its Cauchy pprincipal value does not exists as `Limit[Integrate[(Exp[\[ImaginaryJ] k x])^2, {x, -a, a}, 
  Assumptions -> a > 0], a -> Infinity]` produces and the same with the denominator.

Comment: @user64494, I interpreted the question differently: Why do the integrals not cancel no matter what the integrand is?  In any case, due to `HoldForm` the integral does not evaluate at all.  The issue then is, how to pull `2` from within `Integrate` in the numerator, and then how to convince Mathematica to cancel the two identical expressions.  Experienced users of this site know what to do, but it is not surprising that those less experienced do not.  By the way, it took me a few minutes to realize that `HoldForm` needed to be replaced by `Unevaluated`.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Thank you, your comment and answer are very helpful.

Answer (score 4):

A transformation function must be defined to extract the leading number from within `Integrate`.  Also, `HoldForm` should be replaced by `Unevaluated`.

```
tf[e_] := e /. Integrate[Times[n_?NumericQ, z1__], z2_] :> n Integrate [z1, z2]

Assuming[{U, k} ∈ Reals && k > 0, (
    (Integrate[2 (U Exp[ k x])^2, {x, -∞, ∞}] // Unevaluated)/
    (Integrate[(U Exp[ k x])^2, {x, -∞, ∞}] // Unevaluated)) // 
    FullSimplify[#, TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, tf}] &]
(* 2 *)
```

Comment: ```TransformationFunctions``` seems to be a very useful function that I do not know previously. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @bakerryd123, Check out the `ComplexityFunction` option too.  Best wishes.

Comment: Nice suggestion, thanks!